# A signal that a session has been created ? [for anonymous user]

Tags: django

I can't seem to find the the signal that tie with a 'session created' .
I'm aware of auth signals , but what i want is to populate a session variable for *anonymous* users.

What am i missing ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: subclass django.contrib.sessions.backends.db,
override method create with you signal, and set SESSION_ENGINE to new engine

Comment: will try that & get back to you !
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a session variable for anonymous users, you can do something as simple as `request.session['something'] = True` (or whatever value you want) in the appropriate view. And if you're trying to see if you've seen an anonymous user before, you can just test for the existence of the 'something' key.

Under the hood, django handles cookie setting and creates a session for an anonymous user if you modify the session variable. If the anonymous user already has a session, it simply records the modified state.

Take a look at the session docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/  for more details. It's pretty sophisticated.

Finally, don't forget to clean expired sessions periodically with `./manage.py clearsessions` if sessions are stored in a persistent store.

Comment: How cool! This is EXACTLY how i decided the way to go little earlier and in the midst of writing. Reading back the question & thinking 'man that was not very smart':)

Anyway, i made a helper function that i would read this value from session , and check if it's null then go & populate it with the defaults 'which why i was wanting session created signal in the first place', good day :-)

Comment: I think it's a good question actually. It wasn't obvious to me how anonymous sessions worked for a long time -- it took some serious digging.